# Can I use WindowBuilder (a Java visual editor Eclipse plugin) without GWT support?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder

Can I use [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/tools.windowbuilder/) (a Java visual editor Eclipse plugin) without [Google Web Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) (GWT) support?

I'm a little bit confused about it. It seems that it is integrated with GWT to build Google web applications.

But can I use it to build a GUI for standard Java applications (like [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans))?

I know it sounds silly, but I spend a lot of time to know if is it possible or not, but I couldn't know.

Notice that I am a Mac user, (WindowBuilder on Mac seems not fully supported).

Comment: In your project, command-N, then scroll down until you find the Window Builder section, then pick the kind of app you want (mine are all Swing) and you can choose JPanel, JFrame etc. Works fine on Mac for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WindowBuilder supports creating SWT, RCP, XWT and Swing apps in addition to GWT apps. It is fully supported under Windows, Linux and OSX. It was recently announced that Google is donating the WindowBuilder Engine along with the SWT and Swing tooling to Eclipse.org.

If you are unable to open a non-GWT file and receive an "Unknown GUI toolkit" error, this means that you either have a classpath problem (our project has not been configured to use any UI toolkit) or you have an incomplete installation of WindowBuilder (for example, if you only have the GWT portion of WB loaded, you would not be able to edit SWT or Swing UIs).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible. WindowBuilder supports both Swing and SWT in addition to GWT, and it is fully supported on Mac OS.

I use it frequently for SWT development, on my Mac ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Installing WindowBuilder is not all required plugin. You need also install eRPC, Swing, SWT Designer plugins. For example from here:
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201106211200/3.7/

For me this helps.