# WindowBuilder, no Browser

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, browser, windowbuilder

I'm using Eclipse with Google's WindowBuilder.  When I run my program, WindowBuild launches my browser and my program is displayed in a web.  All very slow.

How do I configure, if possible, WindowBuilder so it does not launch the web browser, similar to how Netbeans runs its programs?

### Edit 1:

This is similar to: [Can I use WindowBuilder without GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566150/can-i-use-windowbuilder-a-java-visual-editor-eclipse-plugin-without-gwt-suppor), but I'm looking for an example or instructions for creating simple non-GWT application.

Comment: What kind of applications do you build? Swing? SWT? How do they show in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the down arrow near the run button, then click run as and run as a java application. This should not run in your browser.

This may depend on what type of project you have declared your project as.
Try to use the swt package.